# Rewrite part of BibTeX file on reading?

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, italic

I use Mendeley to manage my bibliography, pdf's, and to generate BibTeX files. It has one serious bug for me: an italicized word in a title (e.g, a scientific name of an organism) is written to the .bib file as

```
{\textless}i{\textgreater}Hordeum spontaneum{\textless}/i{\textgreater}
```

rather than

```
\textit{Hordeum spontaneum}.
```

In other words, they're translating something like html *name* into LaTeX. LaTeX, of course, prints this literally.

No amount of pleading on their help boards, by a variety of people, has succeeded in getting them to fix this. The alternatives amount to either going through one's .bib files with a search/replace, or running a Python script someone wrote to do the same thing. The difficulty is that one would have to do this every time the .bib file is overwritten by Mendeley, i.e., every time one edits any entry.

But it occurs to me that there might be a way (well beyond my command of BibTeX) to write something in the .tex code that says, essentially,

```
\AtEveryBibItem{if the title contains {\textless}i{\textgreater} }{replace it with \textit{ }{}
\AtEveryBibItem{if the title contains {\textless}\i{\textgreater} }{replace it with } }{}
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[nobib, sfsidenotes]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage[natbib, bibstyle=authoryear, dashed=true, backend=biber,
  doi=false, url=false, arxiv=false, isbn=false, eprint=false, 
  autocite=inline, backref=true, citestyle=verbose, giveninits=true]
  {biblatex}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
    @article{King2011,
    author = {King, E G and Roff, D A and Fairbairn, D J},
    journal = {Journal of Evolutionary Biology},
    language = {en},
    number = {2},
    pages = {256--264},
    shorttitle = {Trade-off acquisition and allocation in Gryllus fi},
    title = {{Trade-off acquisition and allocation in 
      {\textless}i{\textgreater}Gryllus firmus{\textless}/i{\textgreater}: a 
      test of the Y model}},
    volume = {24},
    year = {2011}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
%
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Cat1}
\defbibheading{Cat1}{\color{blue}\section*{Cat1}}
%
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Read}
\defbibheading{Read}{\color{ProcessBlue}\section*{Read}} 
%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55
% Get rid of "In:"
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
%
% Add colon and space after volume
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
%
% Get rid of paretheses around year
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}
%
\usepackage{bibentry}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=20,minnames=1,maxcitenames=2, 
    citetracker=true,
    ibidtracker=constrict, loccittracker=constrict}%,
%
% Biber directives to prevent use of number and month fields, prevents 
  printing in journal entries
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=number, null]
      \step[fieldset=month, null]
    }
  }
}
%
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}         
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{\unspace\nopunct}         
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}                   
% turn off quote marks for titles
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,
  patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1\isdot}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {page},% originally "cited on page"
  backrefpages = {pages},% originally "cited on pages"
}
%
\newcommand{\addcite}[2]{%
{\color{blue}\cite{#2}}\addtocategory{#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\donecite}[2]{%
    {\color{ProcessBlue}\cite{#2}}\addtocategory{Read}{#2}
}
% Get rid of extraneous language info %
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearlist{language}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

No offense to the author, but I read this and I'm just getting crickets: \donecite{Cat1}{King2011}
%
%
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
%
\bibbycategory
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's no doubt possible from tex but the bib file is just wrong, and unmaintainable in the longer term, better I think to wrap mendely in some script that fixes up the generated bib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\zz{%
\def\textless{\aftergroup\zztextless}}

\def\zztextless#1#2#3{%
\ifx i#1\begingroup\itshape#3\else
\ifx /#1\endgroup\fi\fi}


\begin{document}

\begin{zz}
Please don't use  {\textless}i{\textgreater}this{\textless}/i{\textgreater},
fix the  {\textless}i{\textgreater}input{\textless}/i{\textgreater} instead!

\end{zz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I hate to bring the bad news, but the content in the bbl looks like this after the biber processing: `\field{title}{{Trade-off acquisition and allocation in {<}i{>}Gryllus firmus{<}/i{>}: a test of the Y model}}`.(not quite sure if this a good idea of biber ... I think I will ask @moewe about it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if the OP follows the advice in the answer, this is an irrelevant detail;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the wrong content with a source map:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
    @article{King2011,
    author = {King, E G and Roff, D A and Fairbairn, D J},
    journal = {Journal of Evolutionary Biology},
    language = {en},
    number = {2},
    pages = {256--264},
    shorttitle = {Trade-off acquisition and allocation in Gryllus fi},
    title = {{Trade-off acquisition and allocation in
      {\textless}i{\textgreater}Gryllus firmus{\textless}/i{\textgreater}: a
      test of the Y model}},
    volume = {24},
    year = {2011}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
%
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = \regexp{{&lt;}i{&gt;}},
          replace = \regexp{\\textit\{}]
        \step[fieldsource = title,
          match = \regexp{{&lt;}/i{&gt;}},
          replace = \regexp{\}}]
    }
  }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

No offense to the author, but I read this and I'm just getting crickets: \cite{King2011}
%
%
\printbibliography
%
%
\end{document}
```

The resulting .bbl has then this entry:

```
 \field{title}{{Trade-off acquisition and allocation in \textit{Gryllus firmus}: a test of the Y model}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling, I gave up on the solution of fixing within TeX (and will accept David's initial answer). There's a Python (2.7) script online that, with a minor bit of adaptation, works - see  https://itskathylam.wordpress.com/2016/01/12/dealing-with-italics-in-bibtex-files-exported-from-mendeley/. I had to adapt it slightly to get it to work, but it works on my pc.

Another source that may be useful is https://github.com/scotartt/clean_bib

Still another is https://ramblingacademic.com/2016/06/fixing-bibtex-files-mendeley/

I haven't tried these.